# sequence deleting from specific character using excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 6 columns and 65000 cells with most of same following contend;
A1 = Electrical ~ Lighting ~ Flashlights ~ Lanterns ~ Fulton ~ Waterproof
...

F4 = Electrical ~ Lighting ~ Flashlights ~ Lanterns ~ Fulton ~ Waterproof

I want each column with "Electrical, Lighting, Flashlights, Lanterns, Fulton, Waterproof" respectively, so the result it will be each name on each column.

Thank you

Alex

Comment: that looks like a question for rent-a-coder.com isn't it ?

Comment: I don't think so. I just trying to figure a formula that give me to separate each name for each column

Comment: in VBA, use the Split() function

Comment: I am using SUBSTITUTE(B24,"~","@",LEN(B24)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B24,"~",""))) but no yet

Comment: yes, I tried this function in vb (Function PullAfterLast(rCell As Range, strLast As String)
    PullAfterLast = Mid(rCell, InStrRev(rCell, strLast) + 1, 256)
End Function), but didn't' work

Comment: Are you trying to replace " ~ " with ", "?  Or are you trying to split the values separated with the tilde (~) into separate columns?  If it is a 'search & replace', just the Excel's Search & Replace feature.  It is very good at replacing the right parts within each cell.

Comment: One more comment -- if you are trying to split the values into separate columns, Excel has a feature for that too called "Text to Columns" (depending on the version of Excel)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA you can use the Split() function, but it's not available as a worksheet function.
Otherwise, that's alread built in Excel: menu `Data`, option `Text to column`.
If you need to program it, use the recorder and come back with a programming question, if you have trouble.

Comment: @user1229266: welcome to stackoverflow, if this answer fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it using VBA and double transposing an array (a very nifty trick).
**UDPATE**: no need to double transpose the array (thanks, JFC!). Fixed code.

```
Sub SplitEmUp()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As range
Dim items As Variant

lastRow = range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    If InStr(cell, " ~ ") Then
        items = Split(cell, " ~ ")
        range(cell.Address).Resize(, UBound(items)).Value = items
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Double transpose is a nifty trick but is useless in this particular case... But +1 for bringing to my attention the fact that `Resize` has *optional* arguments! I don't know how many times I struggled with `Resize` because I didn't know this.

Comment: Single transpose will do it verticle - to transpose horizontally you need to double it up (as far as I know). :)

Comment: Yes, but one-dimensional arrays are taken to be horizontal by default! So you're taking an array that is horizontal to start with, making it vertical, and then making it horizontal again... Might as well skip the double transpose. To convince yourself, try `[...].Value = items`.

Comment: Also if brevity is desirable,  `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose` can also be written as `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` -- or even `Application.Transpose` which is not documented as far as I can tell... never understood why!